# Stop Chrome pop-up blocked message on React js

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

in our application, when a user click on a link, we open a new browser tab and shows a PDF to the user(*the pdf is actually a base64 stream that we send from the server and it works all fine*). We however noticed that on production environment (*running on HTTPS*), user was presented with a pop-up blocked icon and user is forced to click on it to see that PDF in adjacent tab. This issue is not coming on local machine though. We do not want Chrome to show this pop-up blocked to the user. Can you please help me here?

We are using this code to open the pdf...

```
let pdfWindow = window.open("");
pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0' src='data:application/pdf;base64," + encodeURI(response.base64Stream)+"'></iframe>");
```

Comment: Look into progressive web apps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was opening the new tab after my api response and this activity was suspicious to the browser. The solution is to first open the tab and then make api call. Once api response is received, show the api data in the tab. This worked